# Want to know how does this line work. int j = list.size() - i - 1;

Tags: java

```
enter code here
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int j = list.size() - i - 1; // HOW DOES THIS LINE WORK
        result.add(list.get(j));
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

HOW DOES THIS LINE WORK. int j = list.size() - i - 1;

Comment: It's a simple subtraction between integer values.

Comment: It works as follows: `int j = list.size() - i - 1;`

Comment: debug your code!

Answer (score 0):

list.size() declares the size of the list (total number of elements in the list), and i is iterator.
if list size is 10 then for the first iteration, int j = 10 - 0 - 1 = 9. 
Hence it'll add the element of index 9 which will be added to the result. As the loop continues, index number will keep decreasing and add them in results